# Error with MonoDevelop

Tags: .net, monodevelop

I just installed MonoDevelop on my Ubuntu Partition.  None of my VB.net apps will debug because of the error:

`Visual Basic .NET compiler no found (Mono 2.6.7)`

How can I correct this?  I have limited experience with Ubuntu so... well you get the point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you will find this link helpful: http://codingexplorer.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/asp-net-with-vbnet-applications-on-ubuntu-10-10/

Basically, you need to install [Mono Visual Basic Compiler for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+package/mono-vbnc) and then you should be all set. You might need to look for another link suitable for your Ubuntu distribution.

Also, there is [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/309168/error-visual-basic-net-compiler-not-found-mono-2-6-7-first-mononet-app) with an answer on SuperUser.